# Cypher match in the while loop

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there any possible to do the same work for `while(condition){....}` in Cypher?

For example:

```
while(x>300){x-300}
```

So only when x <300 it will stop the while loop which means it will stop keeping match in cypher.
Here is my query:

```
MATCH p=(n:Label{updatetime:'2017/5/1 6:30'})-[r:GO_TO{routeid:'1'}]->()
MATCH p1=(n1:Label{updatetime:'2017/5/1 6:30'})-[r1:GO_TO{routeid:'2'}]->() 
MATCH p2=(n2:Label{updatetime:'2017/5/1 6:30'})-[r2:GO_TO{routeid:'3'}]->() 
MATCH p3=(n3:Label{updatetime:'2017/5/1 6:35'})-[r3:GO_TO{routeid:'4'}]->() 
MATCH p4=(n4:Label{updatetime:'2017/5/1 6:45'})-[r4:GO_TO{routeid:'5'}]->() 
MATCH p5=(n5:Label{updatetime:'2017/5/1 6:45'})-[r5:GO_TO{routeid:'6'}]->() 
MATCH p6=(n6:Label{updatetime:'2017/5/1 6:50'})-[r6:GO_TO{routeid:'7'}]->()
```

Comment: Cypher has no while loop, please share your code what have you tried

Comment: what about setting condition to execute something? any possible? 

I may get 100 routeid for this. So how can I use loop to execute this. node properties `Updatetime` are also different in each routeid. @Tomaž Bratanič

Comment: so you want to get the first 300 routeids ? or just the first 300 results... where does the x stands in your `match` pattern ?

Comment: for programming logic, you could delegate that work to a Java service that calls the REST API or Neo4j directly. Otherwise, what Tom said (What is the logic of the while loop?)

Comment: Sorry for the formmating......Thanks!!!! I have changed my way to java.It's work.By the way,I have plugin apoc procedure in neo4j browser, but when I change to Java Eclipse and execute the query it shows error
 `There is no procedure registered for this database instance.`
Here is my java code
`gdbs.execute("MATCH (gli:label{pointname:'A'}),(gli2:label{pointname:'B'})
call apoc.algo.dijkstra(gli,gli2,'GO_TO3>','traveltime') yield path ,weight
return extract(r in relationships(p)|r.routeid) as path");
System.out.println(result.resultAsString());`@Tezra

Comment: @LinBernie That is a new question, that I think is already on SO. Does the query work in the browser?

Comment: Is it possible with cypher ? I'm searching "MATCH" inside a for/while loop statement